# Parsing/Copying Pointer/arrays into struct with semicolon bit field constraint

Tags: c, struct

My question is this.

My processor has a minimum of 16bit width for data types.

However I have some structs that are supposed to be 8 bits wide. This is some legacy code that i am trying to port, so these structs are getting parsed from some array or pointer to data.

Does using semi colons allow me to constrain the parsing of the information to 8 bits when the variable is being parsed from pointer to struct?

UPDATE: Example

```
struct  CANMDL_BYTES {      // bits   description
   Uint16      BYTE3:8;     // 31:24
   Uint16      BYTE2:8;     // 23:16
   Uint16      BYTE1:8;     // 15:8
   Uint16      BYTE0:8;     // 7:0
};
```

If i tried to cast an array into this struct, will it cast correctly? Consider that my array is using all bits regardless of the data type

Comment: Really not clear what you are talking about. Please show some code to better clarify what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making the assumption that when you say you need a struct that is 8 bits wide, you are referring to bitfields.

In which case you can have an 8 bit bitfield struct such as:

```
struct My8BitStruct
{
    uint8_t    SomeField    : 3;
    uint8_t    AnotherField : 5;
};
```

This struct will have `sizeof(My8BitStruct) == 1` which is 8 bit. The structure contains two fields, one 3 bit field and one 5 bit field.

Note however that making a bitfield that is not using the native `int` type is not standard C. However you will find most compilers support this extension.

Comment: Ok yes this is exactly the answer i am looking for. Thank you. Although it means that i have wasted a heck of a long time doing it some other stupid method.